# How to get selected row in html table which is binded by sql using jquery and webservice?

Tags: jquery

Am trying to get the value which is binded in html table using Jquery and webservice but the event is not firing where the values bind by jquery but the event is firing when i am binding from html but i want when the table is binded by jquery only

please help me ...

My code is like this

**Jquery to print selected row's id**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#tbDetails tr').click(function (event) {
    alert($(this).attr('Eid'));       
});
});
```

**Jquery binded from webservice**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../../Services/Employee/BindEmployees.asmx/BindDatatable",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
            $("#tbDetails").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].Eid + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Ename + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Edesg + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Edept + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Edoj + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Etype + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Epfno + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Ebankac + "</td></tr>");
        }
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
});
```

Binding is working fine but the only problem is when am trying to get the value from select **tablerow** it is not firing ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you attach the `click` event to your `tr` elements when the page is loaded, therefore the `click` event handler will not be attached to `tr` elements created later than the page is loaded. Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#tbDetails').on("click", "tr", function (event) {
    alert($(this).attr('Eid'));       
});
});
```

This will apply for future `tr` items as well inside `#tbDetails`.

Comment: I got your point ... I got it by calling like this Thank you .... i have query the data in alert am getting as undefined can  u please help me how to get correct value

Comment: $(this).attr('Eid') is undefined, since there is no Eid="somevalue" inside the tr tag definition. Instead you want to get the inner text of the first td, like this: $(this).find("td:first").text()